# Need help with comma placement in relation to sense of sentence

Tags: commas

I'm puzzling over the following sentence from a chapter I'm proofreading:

"We all have homes, and jobs to go to in the morning."

My brief is to only make changes where it is absolutely necessary i.e. only if it is necessary in clarifying the sense, not simply improving the style.

I'm guessing the author probably put the comma in to clarify that the speaker is going to their home tonight and to their job the next morning. But I still think it doesn't quite work and will be a bit jarring for the reader.

Would the sense be clearer if it was changed to:
"We all have homes to go to and jobs in the morning." ?
(Does this need a comma before 'and'?)

If there is agreement that the original sentence is perfectly acceptable then I will just let it be!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Without the comma, it sounds like they went to the homes in the morning too.

Comment: 'My brief is to only make changes where it is absolutely necessary i.e. only if it is necessary in clarifying the sense, not simply improving the style' and  'But I still think it ... will be a bit jarring for the reader' seem self-contradictory. // Clarity-wise, it's fine. // Stylewise, there _is_ a jarring that 'We all have homes and jobs' or 'We all have homes; we all jobs' removes (by being better balanced), but these sound rather bland. Your suggested paraphrase is unidiomatic (unlike 'jobs _to go to_ in the morning'). The jarring effect of the original is not unattractive. I'd leave it.

Comment: The sentence is understandable exactly as it is. Changing it (especially removing the comma) would make the meaning less clear or the sentence more long-winded (depending on what you changed). However, if you insist on a change, I suggest this: *We all have homes, and we all have jobs to go to in the morning.*